# How to make a minimap of the whole page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am working on a simple JS/HTML/CSS project. I have a box that's very big (400vw, 400vh) and it acts like a map. What I want to do is a mini-map for that huge thing on the top left corner.

What I understand is that it has to be done with canvas by getting the whole page, put it in canvas and then display it in another box that's just for example 10 times smaller. If my logic is correct, then what is wrong in the code?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script defer src="js/main.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <style>
        #minimapCanvas {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
        }
      </style>
      <script>
        window.onload = function() {
          // Get the canvas element and its context
          var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
          // Draw something on the main canvas

          context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
          saveCanvas();
        }
  
        function saveCanvas() {
          // Get the canvas element and its context
          var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
          // Get the image data from the canvas
          var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
          // Create a new canvas for the minimap
          var minimapCanvas = document.getElementById("minimapCanvas");
          minimapCanvas.width = 100;
          minimapCanvas.height = 100;
          var minimapContext = minimapCanvas.getContext("2d");
  
          // Draw the image data on the minimap canvas
          minimapContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0, 0, 0, minimapCanvas.width, minimapCanvas.height);
        }
      </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
   <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
   <canvas id="minimapCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and after I run the application I get a big black box instead of the minimap -
[image]

I have been trying to search every possible topic about JS mini-map in stackoverflow but couldn't find my solution. I also tried Chat GPT (which usually helps me).

EDIT:
Here is a github link to my repository (NOTE: you have to run it with a live server for example in VSCode, in order for the character's image to work properly) -
https://github.com/ApooBG/minimap

Comment: The code works for me, but it does not show how you put the image in the big canvas.

Comment: Didn't quite get it, I should put the variable `imageData` in `myCanvas` and display it?

Comment: The code you shared does not explain how you filled the big canvas with the image shown in your screenshot. I suspect the problem lies in the code you did not share.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen The thing is that I shared everything. If something is missing, like you are saying, then my logic is just bad. The other things are html divs, nothing else, so could you explain to me a bit more in detail what I need to add

Comment: You did not share the `js/main.js` and `app.js` files. When I run your code without these, I only get a black filled square in the big canvas, plus a correct minimap version of it.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I updated my post with a github repository where you can check everything. The app.js file was for testing other things, so I have removed it as it was now unused.